I need a script for SCCM detection key to Match Value Data
/* I need a script SCCM detection key for match "Value Data" in "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" Without using "ValueName" Match "ValueData".*/
How to resolve this issue?
$properties = Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath

Enumerate all the keys using Get-ChildItem, then use the synthetic Property property on each key to discover the attached property names, then finally test the value of each until you find a matching one:
# define search term and parent key
$searchTerm = 'ValueDataGoesHere'
$parentKey = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'

# locate all matching keys
$matchingKeys = @(
  # enumerate subkeys under parent
  Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $parentKey |Where-Object {
    $key = $_
    # test each value for the search term until at least 1 is found
    $key.Property.Where({
      ($key |Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name $_) -eq $searchTerm
    }, 'First').Count -gt 0
  }
)

$matchingKeys will contain an array with any and all subkey that had a value entry containing the exact search term
If you want substring search (or want to implement a more complicated condition for the value), simply edit the comparison operation in the .Where({...}) call:
($key |Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name $_) -match ([regex]::Escape($searchTerm))


@CHANAMARLAKIRAN Did you output anything? I haven't used SCCM in half a decade, but usually you need to output something to indicate a successful detection.

In SCCM detection key when we use script need to indicate output "0" (true). for Example below script.
$sap64 = ((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*).DisplayName -match "SAP Business Explorer")
$sap32 = ((gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*).DisplayName -match "SAP Business Explorer")
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($sap64)) {
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($sap32)) {$true}
}
like this I need but here searching ValueName (Display). randomly need to check all keys and match ValueData
